# how to get the cheapest NFT in a collection using Magic Eden API

Tags: python, api, python-requests, nft

How can I get the cheapest NFT in a collection using the Magic Eden API? I thought about using the `/collections/:symbol/listings` endpoint, retrieving all listed NFTs and get the cheapest one, but the max amount the endpoint returns is 20.

API docs: https://api.magiceden.dev/